# Java (generating numbers with no repeats )

Tags: java, android, random, numbers

I am making an app and the code underneath is supposed to generate 7 random numbers and print them to screen and none of the numbers should be same as the other.

I have tried every way of doing this. I have spent some 5 hours checking it, getting second opinions and they say it should work but it doesn't. 
What does it do? It just writes 7 random numbers to the screen but most of the time there are duplicates, most of the time the app just stops (error), but there is no error in the code. This is only one way out of many ways that I've tried. 
Could some one please tell me if something is not right? or have a suggestion? or be so kind to give me some example code to replace to while loop? Any advice would be great bearing in mind I am quite new to java.

**Update**: The while loop is the main loop. it call a numbers method and that make 7 random numbers and stores them in "text_counter" array, then i check to see if they are repeated numbers in the array if not, it breaks out of the loop and prints them to the screen, however if there are it goes back to the beginning of the loop to generate more random numbers and check them again.

Here is the code

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Lotto extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Random dice = new Random();
TextView top, med, and, qcounter, wcounter, ecounter, rcounter, tcounter,
        ycounter, ucounter;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Set uniqueItems = new HashSet();
Button gen;
EditText input1, input2;
int[] text_counter = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
boolean o = false;
boolean oo = false;
boolean ooo = false;
int text1;
int pre_text2;
int count = 0;
int text2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lotto_xml);
    gen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_gen);
    // ////////////////////////////////////// text view var
    qcounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q_lotto);
    wcounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.w_lotto);
    ecounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e_lotto);
    rcounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.r_lotto);
    tcounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_lotto);
    ycounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y_lotto);
    ucounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.u_lotto);
    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    final EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_min);
    final EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_max);

    gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            o = false;
            oo = false;
            count = 0;

            while (o == false) {
                number();
                count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < text_counter.length; i++) {
                    if (!uniqueItems.add(text_counter[i])) {
                        count = count + 1;
                    }

                }

                if (count == 0) {
                    o = true;
                }

            }

            qcounter.setText(String.valueOf(text_counter[0]) + ",");
            wcounter.setText(String.valueOf(text_counter[1]) + ",");
            ecounter.setText(String.valueOf(text_counter[2]) + ",");
            rcounter.setText(String.valueOf(text_counter[3]) + ",");
            tcounter.setText(String.valueOf(text_counter[4]) + ",");
            ycounter.setText(String.valueOf(text_counter[5]) + ",");
            ucounter.setText(String.valueOf(text_counter[6]));

        }


        private void number() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            text1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString());
            text2 = Integer.parseInt(input2.getText().toString());
            text2 = text2 - text1;
            text2 = text2 + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                text_counter[i] = text1 + dice.nextInt(text2);
            }
        }

    });

}
}
```

Comment: If the app "stops (error)" then there is definitely an "error in the code".

Comment: The app just stops responding and force closes, it might be stuck in the loop or something, i was just intending it was some type of error.

Comment: `String.valueOf(text_counter[0]) + ","` is the same as `text_counter[0] + ","`

Comment: If you're guaranteeing that there are no duplicates, then the numbers aren't truly random.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak what's "truly random"? http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never clear the HashSet called `uniqueItems`. You should clear it before each loop, otherwise you will keep accumulating numbers in there forever.

Comment: with a method perhaps called `clear()`?  Duh! Please do not ask questions at StackOverflow which can be trivially answered by just taking a very quick look at the documentation.

Comment: @MikeNakis What's with the attitude?

Comment: @EliAcherkan I suppose I have issues.

Comment: It's okay, I have the same issues. They come from dedicating your own time to answering questions from people on SO who are just completely helpless and can't be bothered to try and find answers for themselves.

Comment: @MikeNakis I always wonder why some people would ask a question (how to clear it?) which takes 5 sec to answer using the IDE you have already opened. It is **faster** to get answer from IDE than from forum, so why waste someone's  precious personal time?

Comment: @PeterMasiar yes, it is one of humanity's great mysteries to me, too, Peter.

Comment: @MikeNakis -  Programming is a battle between programmers writing better, smarter, more fool-proof programs, and universe making better fools. So far, universe is winning. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking if the array has duplicates and trying again, check if the most recently generated number is already in the array before adding it. If it is, you can generate the number again without throwing away your previous work.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

A simple way is to generate numbers and put them in a `hashmap`. You keep generating until you have 7 numbers that are unique. If you hit a collision you regenerate.

A better idea, but which uses more memory, is to have an array of bits of some size. Each bit represents a number. Then you generate random numbers:

```
while (counter != 7){
  randomNumber= ...Random.nextInt();
  if ([randomNumber % bitArray.length] != 0){
     print(randomNumber % bitArray.length)
     [randomNumber % bitArray.length]= 0;
     counter++
   }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating all new numbers, how about doing the following

```
private void number() {
    text1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString());
    text2 = Integer.parseInt(input2.getText().toString());
    text2 = text2 - text1;
    text2 = text2 + 1;
    if (text2 < 7) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not generate 7 unique renumbers between " + text1 + " and " + (text1 + text2));
    }
    int[] text_counter = new int[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        boolean duplicate;
        do {
            text_counter [i] = text1 + dice.nextInt(text2);
            duplicate = false; // Starting assumption
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (text_counter[j] == text_counter[i]) {
                    duplicate = true;
                }
            }
        } while (duplicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the check was wrong (should not have typed the code without testing it)